# Snmptrapd not handle all traps

Tags: linux, centos, snmp

Morning everyone,

After passing a lot of time searching a solution and a lot of headaches, i'm coming to you hoping an explanation ;-)

So, I want to receive trap from my routers and specialy `"LinkDown"` and `"LinkUp"`.
The router send the informations to my server, doing tcpdump we can see the traps coming.

My problem is snmptrapd. Verifying in the logs, (/var/log/snmptrapd.log) I see only 1 trap on 3 almost.

I tried from another server to send traps in command line

```
snmptrap -v2c -c public @IP '' .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 ifIndex i 541 ifAdminStatus i 1 ifOperStatus i 2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.541 s "eth1"
```

and i have same problem => 1/3 trap received by snmptrapd.

I'm totaly lost and i can't see what the problem, and where to check.

I'm waiting your advises and your lights !

I'm on `CentOS 6.7 (running Centreon 2.7.0`)

EDIT May 9 2016 ---
Ok, the problem came from that too many traps entered my server and some was not handle by snmptrapd.
I put a firewall rule that drop all the incoming trap except from the router on which i'm doing tests. And all the trap are now handle.
I just have to check how many trap can be handle by snmptrapd, if someone have the answer you're welcome.

And thanks to all who took time to answers me.

Comment: You can only analyze network packets via Wireshark on both sides to see where the UDP packets go. Otherwise, there is really no way to tell, as UDP is by design unreliable.

Comment: HI Lex Li, Thanks for answer, but the command tcpdump is send on the server that need to receive the trap, so normally it snif all the packets that arrive in this server ?

Comment: I am not familiar with tcpdump. You have to check its man page or run a Google search to see if there is any switch to tune. If there is a packet size filter, then it might not capture all packets.

Answer (score 1):

snmptraps are not "safe" by design. If you network has packet loss, traps will get lost. If you ping flood, do you see any loss of traffic?

You should at intervals pull the data aswell as listening for traps.

Comment: HI Stian, I know about this issue but my company ask this feature so i will do it ;-) and the matter is that we have about 900 routers and we need a immediate information about a port going down, and a pulling on each routers on each port (what we are doing right now) is asking a lot of ressources. (right now i can't have another server to do some pollers)

Comment: and about the loss of packet, i think (for now, i'm working on 1 router), i'm sure that my problem is not coming from this.      All my traps are seen by tcpdump, but snmptrapd didn't get all of them o_O.

Comment: Try to dump the traffic to a pcap, and view them in wireshark. Maybe some details are not correct in the traffic dump?

Comment: I see nothing special in wireshark. All the traps seems correct. Meanwhile, I'm not sure what to search.

Comment: How do you start snmptrapd, and do you have a /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf file ?

Does the problem happen if you use localhost?

Comment: snmptrapd start with the init.d, and yes the snmptrapd.conf is present in /etc/snmp/. I didn't tried with localhost i'll try on monday morning and I'll check if problem happen.

Comment: I checked this morning with localhost, I did 2 tests: 1- I test it out of the network (my network card eth0 down) and all my trap was 100% ok. 2 - I test on the network (ifup eth0) and launched 3 LinkDown 100% ok and 1 linkUp 0 % ok. Does the problem can come that i receive a lot of trap and some are not handle ?